# How to manually scroll inside a scrollable container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Let's say I have a list with elements

```
<ul>
<li>elem1</li>
<li>elem2</li>
<li>elem3</li>
<li>elem4</li>
</ul>
```

The ul have max-height, and vertical scrollbar. So I see only two first elements.
Now, I gonna walk through this elements using keyboard (for example by adding "selected" class for a selected element)

The question is: How to manually scroll down to elem3 using javascript / changing styles?

---

UPDATE
Solution: [Jump to content inside of a scrollable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3738050/jump-to-content-inside-of-a-scrollable-div?rq=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try code like this :

```
$('div')[0].scrollTop = 100 // Scroll down by 100px;
```

Edit: *Assuming you have wrapped your ul li content around a div.*
[JSFiddle here!](http://jsfiddle.net/d8pnLah3/)